# Django included urls doesn't work

Tags: python, django

Can't figure out why included urls isn't working. Project has 1 my app. So in myproject/mysite/urls.py i have:

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    ......
    url(r'^sub/', include('subscription.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)
```

Then in myproject/subscription/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from .views import subscribe

urlpatterns = patterns(
    url(r'^subscribe/', subscribe),
)
```

If i try to go to http://localhost:8000/lt/sub/subscribe/ it displays 404 page (Page not found). What might be the problem?

EDITED: Project tree:

```
myproject/
    manage.py
    media/
    static/
    subscription/
        templates/
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        forms.py
        models.py
        urls.py
        views.py
    mysite/
        locale/
        static/
        templates/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
```

Comment: What is it supposed to match with `/lt/`?....

Comment: Oh, it's just a language, if i try http://localhost:8000/sub/subscribe/, it appends url with `/lt/`. It's from django-cms.

Comment: Have you tried using python package instead of string in `include`. Like this `url(r'^sub/', include(subscription.urls))`?

Comment: Yes, now in console error: `   url(r'^sub/', include(subscription.urls)),
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urls'`.

Comment: Can you show your project tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in calling the [`patterns()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/urls/#patterns) function:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    url(r'^subscribe/', subscribe),
)
```

`patterns()` accepts a view prefix as the first argument, if you pass an `url()` instance, this will not be used as a url pattern. If you had any other url patterns, this would give you an error, but in this specific case `patterns()` will simply return an empty list.

Since `patterns()` is deprecated, it is better to switch to the new-style url configuration, and use a list:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^subscribe/', subscribe),
]
```

Otherwise you'd have to pass a prefix as the first argument. Since you don't actually use the prefix (you pass a view function, not the import location as a string), this would generally be the empty string `''`.

Answer (score 0):

> if i try localhost:8000/sub/subscribe, it appends url with /lt/

Thats because your url pattern requires a trailing slash, which you haven't provided

```
r'^subscribe/'  # Shouldn't have the slash or should be optional
```

Normally this wouldn't be a problem since djangos [`APPEND_SLASH`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#append-slash) would help you out (if you're using `CommonMiddleware`) but it would seem that django-cms has a catch-all redirect applied on your application to redirect to a locale.

Comment: Still doesn't work if i remove`url(r'^subscribe', subscribe),` slash from there.

Comment: @Mažas - Describe "doesn't work", I'm guessing you have a different error now. You should update your question with the full stack trace.

Comment: Error is same - 404 page not found.